# Use SQL Scalar function in DFT

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, ssis-2012, non-ascii-characters

I have .txt source file which contains `NonASCII` Characters. We have a scalar function in SQl (`[dbo].[RemoveNonASCII]`) how can i use to remove this function in ssis to remove  ASCII characters. I f i can use it in script component. So pl let me know i have a single column which has `ASCII` characters.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

You may need an OLE DB command to run your function for each row on the text file.
If you are unsure how to configure it, please follow these instructions:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/transformations/configure-the-ole-db-command-transformation